# execute javascript onload rather than onchange

Tags: javascript, onload, onchange

I have am HTML form in a PHP page. The form has various inputs. One of the inputs has an onchange event:

```
<input size=10  type=number id=sku1 name=sku1 onchange="showUser(1, this.value);showWhse(1, this.value)">
```

This calls the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function showUser(userNumber, str)  
  {  
    if (str=="")  
    {  
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML="";  
      return;  
    }    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
    {  
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
      {  
        //document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;  
        var description = responseText.substring(12, responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:"));  
        var warehouse = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")+11, responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:"));  
        var sellingUnits = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")+14);  

        document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML = warehouse;  
    document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML = description;  
    document.getElementById("su" + userNumber).innerHTML = sellingUnits;  
  }  
}  
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);  
xmlhttp.send(); 
} 
</script>
```

This works 100%. if however, the input is populated by a session variable, and the page is refreshed, how can I get the script to execute again onload, without an onchange event?

so when the page is first visited, id the input has a value, execute the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute the function onload?

```
window.onload = function init() {
    showUser(1, document.getElementById("sku1").value);
}
```

You may also use the onload attribute of your document's body, or add the init function as an event handler to `DOMContentLoaded`. But I'm sure you already have some functions which are executed onDOMready.

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy! thanks for this. will accept the answer asap!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the ready function from the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  showUser(1, $("#sku1").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) event. You may also want to consider using Jquery's document.ready functionality. The difference can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready). Also, Jquery provides a much more concise syntax for accessing your form elements

In either case, you would probably simply need function that does something like checking the field has a value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function showUserOnLoad()
{
    var inputValue = $('#sku1').val();
    if(inputValue != '' && inputValue != null)
        showUser(1, inputValue);        
}

function showUser(userNumber, str)  
{
    ...
} 
</script>
```